# Jquery validate require from group not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

Having some trouble with this function of the validation plugin:
http://jqueryvalidation.org/require_from_group-method

Related part of the form:

```
<input class="org-group" type="checkbox" name="org[1]" id="org[1]" value="on">
<input class="org-group" type="checkbox" name="org[2]" id="org[2]" value="on">
<input class="org-group" type="checkbox" name="org[3]" id="org[3]" value="on">
```

This list of checkboxes is dynamic. It could have 2 entries, or 50 entries, that's why I am using an array in the form. I want the plugin to ensure that one of the xxx checkboxes in the org-group class is checked.

I use this in the plugin:

```
$( "#orgform" ).validate({
  rules: {
    org[]: {
      require_from_group: [1, ".org-group"]
    },
```

However, it's not working. The form just submits regardless the amount of boxes checked. The "submithandler" works fine. I have some other text fields in this form which are required. If these fields are not filled, the validation runs fine.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure you've referenced all of the required JQuery libraries. If you're using just the **core** library, validation won't work.

Make sure you're also referencing [additional-methods.min.js](https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.14.0/additional-methods.min.js)

[Fiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/yassarikhan786/0soo5zoq/)

Once you have all of the required references, you'll need to modify your html content, so that all of your check boxes have the same `name`. Validation won't work if all of the names are unique. The `ids` will obviously have to remain unique.

**Updated Html**:

```
<form id="orgform">
  <input class="org-group" type="checkbox" name="org" id="org[1]" value="on">
  <input class="org-group" type="checkbox" name="org" id="org[2]" value="on">
  <input class="org-group" type="checkbox" name="org" id="org[3]" value="on">
  <input class="org-group" type="checkbox" name="org" id="org[4]" value="on">
  <input type="submit" value="Validate">
</form>
```

Notice that all of the `checkboxes` have a `name` of "org".

After you've updated your html, update the call to `validate` to reference "org" instead of "org[]". If you inspect the console you'll notice the following error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token [
```

This is because the rules property doesn't accept `[` or `]`

With the html changes, you'll also need to update your JQuery.

**Updated JQuery:**

```
$("#orgform").validate({
  rules: {
    org: {
      require_from_group: [1, ".org-group"]
    }
  }
});
```

**Note:** Please see the Fiddle example I've linked above for a working example.

Comment: I don't know why it doesn't say anything about this in the documentation:  https://jqueryvalidation.org/require_from_group-method/.  As a matter of fact, the documentation does it "wrong"... :(

Comment: @MikeDevenney, please be more specific.  I see nothing wrong in the documentation regarding this method.

Comment: I'm sure something about it annoyed me, hence the quotes around wrong, but 7 months later I have no idea why I wrote that.  Ahhh, I remember now.  I put wrong in quotes because there's nothing wrong with it, it would make more intuitive sense if there was a way to provide a form level rule that any element with the class kphone-group would be considered the group and 1 of them is required.  Since then I have learned more about how the plugin works and while it might have made more sense to back then me, today me understands why it works the way it does.