# jQuery validation require_from_group not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have reviewed a few answers relating to validating including [Jquery validate require from group not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34838412/jquery-validate-require-from-group-not-working)

However, I can not get this to work. I have the following fields:

1. accountName
2. enterPassword
3. accountName1
4. accountName2
5. enterPassword1
6. enterPassword2

Either accountName1 or enterPassword1 must be entered. When I click on the Update button (without entering either of these fields) no error message is displayed.

HTML:

```
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/additional-methods.min.js"></script>

<form data-toggle="validator" role="form" id="contactForm">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="form-signin">

                    <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Please update your account details:</h2>

                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
                        <input id="accountName" name="accountName" type="text" class="input-block-level" placeholder="Current Account">
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></i></span>
                        <input id="enterPassword" name="enterPassword"  type="password" class="input-block-level" placeholder="Current password">
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
                        <input id="accountName1" name="newEntry" type="text" class="input-block-level" placeholder="New account">
                    </div>
                     <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
                        <input id="accountName2" name="accountName2" type="text" class="input-block-level" placeholder="Confirm new account">
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></i></span>
                        <input id="enterPassword1" name="newEntry"  type="password" class="input-block-level" placeholder="New password"
                            data-toggle="tooltip" title="Enter at least 8 characters containing at least 1 lower case, 1 upercase, 1 special and 1 numeric.">
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></i></span>
                        <input id="enterPassword2" name="enterPassword2"  type="password" class="input-block-level" placeholder="Confirm new password"
                            data-toggle="tooltip" title="Enter at least 8 characters containing at least 1 lower case, 1 upercase, 1 special and 1 numeric.">
                    </div>
                    <button id="submit" class="btn btn-large btn-primary" >Update </button>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div> <!-- /row -->
    </form>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$.validator.addMethod(
        "regex",
        function(value, element, regexp) {
            if (regexp.constructor != RegExp)
                regexp = new RegExp(regexp);
            else if (regexp.global)
                regexp.lastIndex = 0;
            return this.optional(element) || regexp.test(value);
        },
        "Please enter correct Characters."
);

$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
$("#contactForm").validate({
    groups: {  // consolidate messages into one
        names: "accountName enterPassword accountName1 enterPassword1 accountName2 enterPassword2 newEntry"
    },
    rules: {
        accountName: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 2
        },

        enterPassword: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 8
        },

        accountName1: {
            require_from_group: [1, ".send"],
            minlength: 2
        },

        accountName2: {
            minlength: 2,
            equalTo: "#accountName1"
        },

        enterPassword1: {
            require_from_group: [1, ".send"],
            regex: /^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[$@$!%*?&])[A-Za-z\d$@$!%*?&]{8,}/,
            minlength: 8
        },

        enterPassword2: {
            regex: /^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[$@$!%*?&])[A-Za-z\d$@$!%*?&]{8,}/,
            minlength: 8,
            equalTo: "#enterPassword1"
        },

        newEntry: {
            require_from_group: [1, ".input-group"]
        },
    },


    messages: {
        accountName: {
            required: "Please enter your current account name.",
            minlength: "Your account name must consist of at least 2 characters."
        },

        enterPassword: {
            required: "Please enter your current password.",
            minlength: "Your password must consist of at least 8 characters."
        },

        accountName1: {
            minlength: "Your account name must consist of at least 2 characters."
        },

        accountName2: {
            minlength: "Your account name must consist of at least 2 characters.",
            equalTo: "Your confirmation account name does not match the original."
        },

        enterPassword1: {
            regex: "Please nter at least 8 characters containing at least 1 lower case, 1 upercase, 1 special and 1 numeric.",
            minlength: "Your password must consist of at least 8 characters."
        },

        enterPassword2: {
            regex: "Please enter at least 8 characters containing at least 1 lower case, 1 upercase, 1 special and 1 numeric.",
            minlength: "Your password must consist of at least 8 characters.",
            equalTo: "Your confirmation password does not match the original."
        }
    },

    submitHandler : function(contactForm) {
        //do something here
        var frm = $('#contactForm');
        //alert($("#accountName1").val());

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "UpdateAccountView",
            cache: false,
            data: frm.serialize(),
            success: function(data){
                console.log('Submission was successful.');
                console.log(data);

                $("#accountName").focus();
                $('#ajaxGetUserServletResponse').text(data);
            }
        });
    }
});      
}); // end document.ready
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've defined your rule...

```
accountName1: {
    require_from_group: [1, ".send"]
....
enterPassword1: {
    require_from_group: [1, ".send"]
....
```

However, none of your fields contain `class="send"` and please be aware that `accountName1` and `enterPassword1` are supposed to match the **`name`** of the field, **NOT** the `id`.

You also have a problem with your `name` attributes in a couple places...

```
<input id="accountName1" name="newEntry" ...

<input id="enterPassword1" name="newEntry"   ...
```

Since the `name` is how the plugin keeps track of inputs, your `name` must match the parameter you're using within your `rules` object of `.validate()` and it should not be duplicated.

You also have the following defined in rules, but this makes no sense...

```
newEntry: {
    require_from_group: [1, ".input-group"]
},
```

Finally, you're including version 1.9 of `additional-methods.js` and we cannot see the version of jQuery Validate.  Note that version 1.9 is VERY old and many bugs with `require_from_group` have been fixed since then.

Otherwise, your code is working:  https://jsfiddle.net/van2havr/

*Note: I disabled the `groups` option for clarity. (and I removed `newEntry` from the list of fields)*

**Another Note:**

You're not leveraging the function's argument provided by the developer that is passed into the `submitHandler`.  You can call it `form` or leave it as `contactForm`.

```
submitHandler : function(contactForm) {

    // var frm = $('#contactForm'); // <-not needed

    $.ajax({
        ....
        data: $(contactForm).serialize(), // <- use it like this
        ....
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Sparky. For "require_from_group: [1, ".send"]" what should I replace ".send" with or where should I place the class please?

Comment: @Glyn, as the per the docs, the second parameter, `.send` in your code, represents a class on the elements in your "group".  It does not have to be a class but can be any jQuery selector that grabs the elements in the "group".   Just refer to the code in my demo above.

Comment: Thank you. I will try to get my head around this over Christmas. I am just learning this and find a lot of the examples contradictory. Yours is the first that has made real sense. Thank you very much.